# Let's not have individual mythical-creature tags?

Tags: discussion

So there were a whole bunch of Medusa edits, and I thought "Why do we need individual mythical-creature tags?"

One isn't really an expert on a single creature, like "werewolves" or "medusa".

So should we have them?

Comment: Why not? What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: It's not really a problem, it's just that these tags are unneccesary

Comment: I disagree. A [medusa] tag tells me a lot more about a question than the hopelessly vague [mythical-creatures]. If it's not pushing other more useful tags out of the way, I see no reason to remove it.

Comment: I agree that *"One isn't really an expert on a single creature, like "werewolves" or "medusa".** I would also agree with @Yannis that the [mythoical-creatures] tag is "hopelessly vague". My opinion is that instead of creating tags like [medusa], it might be more productive to make author tags e.g. [ovid]. The problem is that most of the [greek] questions aren't about a single author. But of course, now that we have a [medusa] tag, I don't see a reason to get rid of it, unless people are unable to use it because there are always five more appropriate tags to use.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with this proposal, using precisely your argument about expertise.

There are mythical creatures in any corpus of mythology. The ancient Greeks had them, the old Norse had them, the Sumerians had them - you get the idea. Now, I'd wager that while it's unlikely that anyone is an expert on just one mythical creature, it's equally unlikely that anyone's an expert on all of them. For instance, someone studying Greek Erinyes won't necessarily know anything about Sumerian dragons.

I also don't think it's necessarily a bad idea to sub-categorize, as it were. [mythical-creatures](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythical-creatures) is currently tied with [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse) as the second most popular tag on the site (behind the ubiquitous [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek)). There's nothing wrong with adding more specific tags, instead of *always* using one vaguer tag.

Comment: I think it is more likely that someone would be an expert in [ovid] than in [medusa]. But the [medusa] tag doesn't necessarily do any harm, unlike the [gods] tag.